# Complexity of sample methods HLSL. O(1), O(n)?

Tags: directx, hlsl, directx-11, directx-9, directx-10

Hy everyone. I wanted to know if someone knew the complexity of the HLSL texture sampling functions, like tex2d and the DX10/11 equivalent. If the texture where a pixel array, it would be of constant complexity access a pixel, but it uses UVs to access the pixel, so I don't know the complexity of the function then. Any one knows?

Comment: It's going to be O(1) because there really isn't any 'n' for it to depend on. It will just calculate the memory address using the provided uv data and index into memory, all of which can be done O(1). I don't immediately find any reference though which is why this is just a comment.

Comment: I wonder why that should actually matter.

Comment: I wanted to know, as i have a loop that uses texture sampling in each iteration, therefor i wanted to know how much will the texture size affect it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### O(1)

I don't know how the HLSL sampling works internally, but I recently built my own (working) samplers for a custom grid class. The difference in performance is caused by the choice of the interpolation method:

#### Point Sampler

The point sampler uses [nearest-neighbour interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation). This algorithm is, of course, very performant, since the UVs are simply rounded to the nearest integer pixel indices.

#### Linear Sampler

This kind produces nicer results, sinces it uses [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation). Assume your UVs point to a location between four pixels. A lerp is then performed on the top pixels in the square, another on the bottom pixels and a third on the results. Since this kind of filtering involves four pixels and 12 float interpolations, it's not as fast as point sampling.

#### Anisotropic Sampler

An anisotropic filter produces the (currently) highest quality results. It is the slowest of the available types.

---

[image: Sampling comparison]

---

- [Texture filtering - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering)

Comment: Texture filters, how didnt i thought of that :facepalm
thanks, thats all i wanted to know