# is there any option to select texture filtering for Xna

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, xna, textures

image : http://www.whitedesing.com/images/Why.png

guys im using a software called "Xna 4.0"

i draw a sprite on photoshop and original resolution is 1897 x 2664 300dpi.. 
im using a command for software, which it is scaling down my sprite.

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, null, null, null, Matrix.CreateScale(.04f, .04f, 1f));
spriteBatch.Draw(_ship, _shipRect,null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(0,0), SpriteEffects.None, 1);
spriteBatch.End();
```

but i cant get a chrisp sprites on Xna.. i can even get a nice look on my windows folder :D (u can see on the picture)
is there any option to change that thing on Xna ? sorry for my bad engilish..

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the [`SamplerState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.samplerstate.aspx) that should be used for texture filtering when you call [`SpriteBatch.Begin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.begin.aspx).

- [Breakdown of the availabel sampling methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14746860/925580)